# theme_hook_suggestions on custom theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a module that implements `HOOK_theme()` to define a 'petition' theme like so:

```
function mymod_theme() {
  return [
    'petititon' => ['variables' => ['foo'=>NULL], 'template' => 'petition']
  ];
}
```

Which I then use like:

```
$some_render_array[] = [ '#theme' => 'petition', '#foo' => 'Bar' ];
```

Which is then rendered by a `petition.tpl.php` template file.

However, I would like to do this:

```
$some_render_array[] = [
  '#theme' => 'petition',
  '#theme_hook_suggestions' => ['petition__1'],
  '#foo' => 'Bar'
];
```

...and have it look for `petition--1.tpl.php`, in the same way you can for nodes, pages etc.

But this doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have a theme that can take a template suggestion? I have a bunch of things to render which all require the same processing but use different templates.

Answer (score 0):

To suggest specific templates you probably need to do it in your theme's template file, use the `hook_preprocess_HOOK` where the first `hook` is the name of your theme and seconde `HOOK` is either `page` to suggest a page template or `node` to suggest a node page.

Here's an example

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  // change the condition to whatever you like
  if(isset($variables['node']) && arg(2) != 'edit')
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $variables['node']->type;
}
```